# how to pass data from conttoller to route

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, routes, middleware

I am trying to pass data from controller to route.

I want to change the status code from a controller to route. let say if in controller status 200 then change it into 400 from routes

or

just simple print hello or something from routes after the response

here is controller  from controller file
contact controller. js

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  Contact.get(function(err, contacts) {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        status: "error",
        message: err
      });
    }

    res.json({
      status: "success",
      message: "Contacts retrieved successfully",
      data: contacts
    });
  });
};
```

here is the route of it from route file
contact router.js

```
var contactController = require('./contactController');

// Contact routes
router.route('/contacts')
    .get(contactController.index)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this article to design you application using express router

https://scotch.io/tutorials/learn-to-use-the-new-router-in-expressjs-4

define your controller like this

```
exports.index = function(req, res, next) {
  Contact.get(function(err, contacts) {
    if (err) {
      next(null,{
        status: "error",
        message: err
      });
    }

    next({
      status: "success",
      message: "Contacts retrieved successfully",
      data: contacts
    },null);
  });
};
```

Define main app file like this

```
var contactController = require('./contactController');
    var router = express.Router();
    // apply the routes to our application
    // route middleware that will happen on every request
    router.use(function(req, res, next) {
        // continue doing what we were doing and go to the route
        next(); 
    });

    // about page route (http://localhost:8080/about)
    router.get('/contacts', function(req, res) {
        //here you can call your controller js method
        contactController.index(req,res, function(data, err){
            //change anything you want here and set into res.
            if(err){
              //change status and data
            }
            else{
               //change status and data 
            }
         })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, you  Man!

Answer (score 0):

Don't end the request-response cycle in the controller, just return the result from the controller instead of ending the cycle.

```
const httperror = require('http-errors');

exports.index = async function(parameter) {
  Contact.get(function(err, contacts) {
    if (err) {
     throw new httperror(400, "Error occured!");
    }

    return {
       status: "success",
       message: "Contacts retrieved successfully",
       data: contacts
    }
  });
};
```

request should start from the route and response should be sent from the route

```
const contactController = require('./contactController');

router.get('/contacts', function (req, res, next) {
   contactController.index()
     .then(result => {
        res.json(result)
     }).catch((error) => {
        res.status(200).json({"Error":"Returned success code 200 even though error 
        occured"});
   })
});
```